# EventHub enable firewall via powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to configure a powershell script to automate eventhub creation. The flow is made at 90% but i didn't know how to enable selected network under firewall and virtual networks.

[image]

i found on doc the cmdlet to add ip restriction:

```
Add-AzEventHubIPRule -ResourceGroupName $rg -NamespaceName $namespace -IpMask myrange
```

and if i run it, it add the ip(if i enable selected network i see the ips) but doesn't enable selected network on azure portal...

there is a way to enable it via powershell?

Thanks
Emanuele

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue and solved using the below code:

```
$IpRules = @([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Models.PSNWRuleSetIpRulesAttributes] @{IpMask = "4.4.4.4";Action = "Allow"},[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Models.PSNWRuleSetIpRulesAttributes] @{IpMask = "3.3.3.3";Action = "Allow"})
$VirtualNetworkRules = @([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Models.PSNWRuleSetVirtualNetworkRulesAttributes]@{Subnet=@{Id="/subscriptions/subscriptionId/resourcegroups/ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/sbehvnettest1/subnets/default"};IgnoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint=$True})
Set-AzEventHubNetworkRuleSet -ResourceGroupName v-ajnavtest -Namespace EventHub-Namespace1-1375 -IPRule $IpRules -VirtualNetworkRule $VirtualNetworkRules -DefaultAction "Deny" -Debug
```

- Added the IP address to the IpRules variable
- Added VNetRules using its required parameters like subnet name, vnet name. (For the subnet name, Open your VNet Resource > Subnets under Settings in the left Index)
- I have changed the `DefaultAction` value to `Deny` so that it will accept the selected IP Address and change the Networking Settings to selected Networks option in the Portal.

**Example:**

```
$IpRules = @([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Models.PSNWRuleSetIpRulesAttributes] @{IpMask = "11.22.33.44";Action = "Allow"},[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Models.PSNWRuleSetIpRulesAttributes] @{IpMask = "11.22.33.44";Action = "Allow"})
$VirtualNetworkRules = @([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Models.PSNWRuleSetVirtualNetworkRulesAttributes]@{Subnet=@{Id="/subscriptions/<yoursubscriptonid>/resourcegroups/krishrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/krishehvnet/subnets/krishehsubnet"};IgnoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint=$True})
Set-AzEventHubNetworkRuleSet -ResourceGroupName krishrg -Namespace krishehhubspace -IPRule $IpRules -VirtualNetworkRule $VirtualNetworkRules -DefaultAction "deny" -Debug
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, i will try it. It enable also virtual network but i don't need beacouse i use private endpoint. I noticed that the option come back to all network when i enable disaster recovery... Primary node have all network and secondary node have selected network. and on primary, if i switch manually to selected network, i see correctly ip restriction.

Comment: Yes @Emanuele, We can enable only Ip Rule under selected networks through PowerShell script. In the example, I taken both Ip Rule and VNet Rule.